# Solving a proof with Fitch

Tags: proof, symbolic-logic, fitch

I'm working on an assignment and I'm stuck on this proof. I feel like I'm on the right track but I can't find the way to prove the goal.

[image]

B ^ D

(B^¬A) → ¬C

B → ¬A

(D^E)→ (A v C)

GOAL: ¬E

Comment: "on the right track"... What have you tried ?

Comment: The conclusion is a negation; so, a possible strategy is to work by contradiction.

Comment: I started by ^elim for B and D, then I did a subproof to start eliminating the conditionals, but how could I prove ~E when ~E is not in the premises? I can't seem to find the logical way to do that.

Comment: Don't put clarifications in the comments.  Please edit your question.  @eaglefern.

Answer (score 2):

> I started by ^elim for B and D, then I did a subproof to start eliminating the conditionals, but how could I prove ~E when ~E is not in the premises? I can't seem to find the logical way to do that.

Good start, but you do not need a subproof to eliminate the conditionals.  It is an in-context inference.

Okay, now the goal is `¬E` when that negation may not be directly derived.  That is an indication to try an indirect proof (a proof of negation).

So assume `E` and seek to derive a contradiction.  Let's get you started.

```
 1.|  B ^ D            premise
 2.|  (B^¬A) → ¬C      premise
 3.|  B → ¬A           premise
 4.|_ (D^E) → (A v C)  premise
 5.|  D                ^elim 1
 6.|  B                ^elim 2
 7.|  ¬A               →elim 3,5
 8.|  B ^ ¬A           ^intro 6,7
 9.|  ¬C               →elim 2,8 
10.|  |_ E             assumption
11.|  |  D ^ E         ^intro 5,10
12.|  |  (A v C)       →elim 4,11
  :|  |  :
  :|  |  :
   |  |  #             ¬elim
   |  ¬E               ¬intro
```

> Well, obviously Proof by Cases is next.

PS: Some Fitch systems do not include a falsum symbol.  Their implementation of negation elimination/introduction may differ somewhat, but the basics are the same.  If a contradiction is derivable when `E` is assumed, then we may infer `¬E`.

Comment: Hi, I tried Proof by cases, but I keep getting errors

Comment: It should be straightforward.  A contradiction may be derived when assuming the left case (`A`) because you may reference line 7 (`¬A`).  A contradiction may also be derived when assuming the right case (`C`) because you can reference line 9 (`¬C`).

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out.